# Compare date and string in PDO

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got the following PDO statement:

```
 $myquery = SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE  TABLE(Date) > 2014-04-07

 $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($myquery); 
 $stmt->execute();
```

I get the following error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

How is it possible to compare a Date in PDO?

Answer (score 1):

Surround the date in single quotes when comparing:

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE  TABLE(Date) > '2014-04-07'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like:

```
$myquery = SELECT * FROM table WHERE  Date > ?

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($myquery,array('2014-04-07')); 
$stmt->execute();
```

even better would be a non string for the date i.e. a datetime-object